# How to get from glGetAttribLocation to glGetActiveAttrib index?

Tags: opengl, shader, opengl-3

I want to query metadata for a given attribute. I hope I have misunderstood how `glGetActiveAttrib` works. Here's what I think how it works:

The attribute *location* can be obtained [using `glGetAttribLocation(programId, attributeName)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml). Metadata can be obtained [using `glGetActiveAttrib(programId, index, ...)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glGetActiveAttrib.xml).

As you can see, `glGetActiveAttrib`  expects an *index* instead of a location.
This is not the same.

#### Example:

In the Shader:

```c
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 textureCoordinate; // <-- this attribute is not used
attribute vec3 normal;
```

In this example, the attribute *locations* will be

```js
locations = [
    position: 0,
    textureCoordinate: -1, // optimized away
    normal: 2, // continues counting the attributes
]
```

However, the active attribute *indices* will be

```js
active_attribute_indices = [
    position: 0,
    // skips texture coordinate because it is not active
    normal: 1, 
]
```

As you can see, the following will not work:

```c
// get attribute location by name
int attrib_location = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "normal"); // = 2

// get attribute metadata
// Error: attrib_location being 2 is not a valid active attribute index.
glGetActiveAttrib(programId, attrib_location, ...)
```

Therefore, my question is:

How can I get the *index* of an active attribute, not the location?

Do I have to loop through *all* attributes and check whether the name matches the name of my attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the [old introspection API](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection#Attributes), there is no way to retrieve an attribute index by name. So you will have to loop through the attribute list to find it.

Under the more [modern introspection API](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection#Interface_query) (available to GL 4.3 and [via extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_program_interface_query.txt)), you can [query any named resource index by name](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection#Resource_indices) (assuming your shader is [not a SPIR-V shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/SPIR-V#Introspection)) via [`glGetProgramResourceIndex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramResourceIndex.xhtml). For vertex shader inputs, you pass the interface `GL_PROGRAM_INPUT`.

Comment: Ok thanks. As I use OpenGL 3.x, I think I will go through all attributes immediately after linking the program, probably putting all attributes into a dictionary. I'll check out the extension, thanks for your links.

Comment: @Johannes: Are you sure you really need to be able to do this? Unless your code is adapting itself to an unknown shader (which is rather rare), there's really little reason to introspect a shader. Also, why are you restricted to GL 3? Nobody is making or selling desktop 3.x hardware anymore.

Comment: Technically, it will run without retrospection. However, I wanted to check if the uniforms and attributes inside the shader have matching types. Because uniforms made it really easy to check their type, I thought that attributes would be quite similar. 
The OpenGL 3.x isn't a strict requirement, but it's the only thing my ancient machine will run. (It refused to run Windows and I had to resort to Linux, where drivers for old hardware are rather problematic).

Comment: I guess it would be possible to just check for an GL_INVALID_VALUE after setting up the attribute, but I'd prefer checking the types only once at compilation time.